# while loop not breaking in the end

Tags: python, while-loop

I made this Hangman Game:

```
wordsList = ["Lampe", "Pflanze", "Bauernhof", "Katze", "Monster", 
"Weihnachtsmann", "Recycling", "Gymnastik", "Metapher", "Zyklop", "YouTube", 
"Playstation", "Artikel 13", "Kokosnuss", "Variable", "Naruto", "Musik", 
"Wandtattoo", "Taschenrechner", "Sonnenblume", "Bilderrahmen", "Videospiel"] 
 #wordslist

while True:
  x = random.randint(0,21) #Random number for choosing a word
  word = []

  print("your word: ", end='')  #show length of the word
  for y in wordsList[x]:
        if y == " ":
            print(" ", end='')
            word.append(" ")
        else:
           print("_ ", end='')
           word.append(0)

  print("")

  fails=0  #number of fails
  rdy=0    #rdy=1 if word is guessed

  while fails<=8:
        hit=0  #if hit=1 a letter was guessed, else fail++
        cnt=0
        inp = input("Input: ")
        for y in wordsList[x]:
            if (inp == y or inp.upper() == y) and word[cnt]==0:
                word[cnt]=y
                hit=1
            cnt+=1
        if hit==0:
            fails+=1
        drawHangman(fails) #draw hangman
        rdy=drawWord(word) #show guessed letters
        if rdy==1: #if rdy=1, finished
            print("")
            print("Well done!!!")
            break

  if rdy==0: #if rdy=0 and not in while-loop, lost
      print("")
      print("Game Over!!!")
      print("The word was: " + wordsList[x])

  print("Again?") #asked if wanna play again, 1=yes 0=no
  print("1: Yes")
  print("0: No")
  inp=input("Input: ")
  if inp==0:
        break
```

Now i got the problem that in the end, when i ask if you wanna play again and you enter 0 for no, the while loop does not break.  Does someone see the problem? I tried using a variable as while-loop-condition and setting it on False if you want to end but the same result. Maybe there is a problem with the indent?

Comment: `input("Input: ")` returns a string. you'd need to cast that to an `int` (or compare with `'0'`).

Comment: @Dominique nope, the `break` is at the correct level

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that input does not store the input as an integer. So you'll end up with the comparison

```
if '0' == 0
```

You need to either cast 0 to string or the input to an integer

```
if int(inp)==0:
```

Answer (score 0):

I would include the condition in the first while:

```
inp = 0
while inp == 0:
   your_code()
   print("Again?") #asked if wanna play again, 1=yes 0=no
   print("1: Yes")
   print("0: No")
   inp=int(input("Input: "))
```

Comment: That's true, edited to get the integer of input. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As already said by others, `input` returns a string.

Either parse the input as an integer

```
if int(inp) == 0:
```

Or you can compare to `'0'`

```
if inp == '0':
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change the `if inp==0:`, to `if inp=="0":` or `if inp=='0':`. You need to make the comparison with the character 0, not the value 0.